# How to create own plugins in activity bar in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I create my own plugins in activity bar, can anyone suggest me the plugin creation in VS code

```
"contributes": {
"menus": {
"editor/title": [{
"when": "resourceLangId == markdown",
"command": "markdown.showPreview",
"alt": "markdown.showPreviewToSide",
"group": "navigation"
}]
}
}
```

Is this the code which i need to refer, how? and where actually should I put it?

I need to create a new plugins for my app

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Need to create new tree-view kind off plugin in VS code

Comment: have you looked at the VSC Extension docs? There is a page on how to add an entry (tab) they are called **Views Container**

Comment: But they are asking me ti register, can you tell me the procedure to register to views container